# How to extract numbers at the end of the strings with repeated pattern in a Pandas column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract all the numbers at the end of the string in a column of a data frame, and make a new column out of them.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'target': ['w1-d2','w1-d3','w1-d5','w1-d9']})
```

Expected result:

```
pd.DataFrame({'target': ['w1-d2','w1-d3','w1-d5','w1-d9'],
              'new_column':['2','3','5','9']})
```

Comment: If the format stays the same (1 digit from the right side), `df['new_column'] = df['target'].str[-1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and a simple regex (`(\d+)$`):

```
df['new_column'] = df['target'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$')
```

output:

```
  target new_column
0  w1-d2          2
1  w1-d3          3
2  w1-d5          5
3  w1-d9          9
```

regex:

```
(    # start capturing
\d+  # match one or more digits
)    # stop capturing
$    # match end of line
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SueryY/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'target': ['w1-d2','w1-d3','w1-d5','w1-d9']})

df['result'] = [i[-1] for i in df['target']]
```

Comment: this is unfortunately non robust (what if there is more than a single digit?) and also non-vectorized (i.e. less efficient)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that all the items of the `target` columns end with a single digit, you could also use a list comprehension to extract it.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'target': ['w1-d2','w1-d3','w1-d5','w1-d9']})
df['new_column'] = [i[-1] for i in df['target'].values]
print(df)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this is unfortunately non robust (what if there is more than a single digit?) and also non-vectorized (i.e. less efficient)

Comment: Completely agree with your opinion about robustness. That is why I firstly indicate certain conditions in order to use the solution I provided. However, the code above does the job for the question asked.